# Django-Python: You must set settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS if DEBUG is False

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, kubernetes

I am trying to deploy a Django-Python based web application in Kubernetes. I'm also trying to setup OpenTelemetry so that I could capture the application metrics and visualise it using prometheus and Grafana.

However, when I try to instrument the application data to the OpenTelemetry collector, I am getting the below error:

> Defaulted container "trojanwall-django" out of: trojanwall-django, opentelemetry-auto-instrumentation-python (init).
> CommandError: You must set settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS if DEBUG is False.

The first line is specifying the name of the Kubernetes pod which is `trojanwall-django` and also saying that OpenTelemetry auto-instrumentation has started. Besides that, the below command says something about the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in the settings.py file.

I tried to add `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]` and also `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost', 'otel-collector.otel.svc.cluster.local', '0.0.0.0']` where `otel-collector.otel.svc.cluster.local` is the host name of the OpenTelemetry collector.

I tried to set `DEBUG = False`, yet still the resulting log is the same. Is this a host blocking issue in the settings.py file?

Below is my settings.py file

**settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for TestProject project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.8.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this:         os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'uzpjcqsdf&@d7#3hrpsdfs__&6%ja)6qsdfvsdoc-=l1*65dxqsxfsd!’

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True
#DEBUG = int(os.environ.get("DEBUG", default=0))


#OTEL Test Config
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost', 'otel-collector.otel.svc.cluster.local', '0.0.0.0']
#ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']



# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'testapp.apps.TestappConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'TestProject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND':     'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]


WSGI_APPLICATION = 'TestProject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_NAME', 'postgres'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_USER', 'postgres'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD', 'postgres'),
        'HOST': os.getenv('POSTGRES_SERVICE_HOST','127.0.0.1'),             
        'PORT': os.getenv('POSTGRES_SERVICE_PORT',5432)
    }
}




# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME':    'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
        {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME':     'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator    ',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
```

(Also please consider the fact that this used to work well and fine. The application works if I disable the auto-instrumentation of OpenTelemetry collector in the Kubernetes pod level. When the container starts, the first command that gets executed is the `python manage.py run server 0.0.0.0:8000`. However, when enabling OpenTelemetry instrumentation in the Kubernetes level, before the container starts its first execution, OpenTelemetry tries to inject something which auto-instruments the application metric data I assume. Could that have messed up anything in Django?)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you show the DEBUG and ALLOWED_HOSTS section of your settings.py?

Comment: Hi. I have added the settings.py file in full. Please have a look.

Comment: I would assume your settings aren't being read correctly. "when I try to instrument the application data to the OpenTelemetry collector" – how are you doing that?

Comment: In the deployment file of the web application we need to add an annotation `instrumentation.opentelemetry.io/inject-python: 'true'`. The instrumentation is also deployed into the same cluster and same namespace as that of the application pod. The instrumentation checks for any pod running with the above mentioned annotation. If it finds any, when the pod starts running, it ingests something which enables the OpenTelemetry collector to scrape data from the application. Please refer the documentation: https://opentelemetry.io/docs/kubernetes/operator/automatic/

Comment: Do you get the error when DEBUG = True? or only when it is set to False?

Comment: Both. I am getting the same error over and over again.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue when attempting to auto instrument locally. I am not sure but it seems that Django settings are being overwritten. I got it working by running `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myapp.settings opentelemetry-instrument ...`. Idk how this would translate to you setup but it might be worth something! FYI there seem to be some open issues related to this https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python-contrib/issues/677 https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python-contrib/issues/2023